# Installing a ceiling light fixture in USA that was purchased in HongKong?

Tags: electrical

I purchased a light fixture on a recent trip to HongKong and someone told me that it would not be compatible with USA. Is this true and if so is there an easy way to convert it so I will be able to safely use it here?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple light fixture that does nothing more than hold bulbs, there's only a couple things to check.

## Socket base

The first thing to check is the socket base(s), size and shape. I'm not sure what's common in Hong Kong, but you'll want to make sure bulbs from the US can fit in the sockets.

## Wire size

The next thing to check is the size of the wires in the fixture. You'll want to make sure they're large enough to handle the load of the lamp(s). It will completely depend on how the fixture is wired, but 18 AWG - 14 AWG is common in US fixtures.

Comment: I would add "insulation and wiring quality" -- unless he knows that the wiring was manufactured to known, modern safety standards for 120VAC wiring, I'd re-wire the whole thing. They could have used low voltage wiring that could suffer an insulation breakdown at some point, or the insulation could harden and crack after a short time. There're definitely quality goods available in Hong Kong, but I've seen some pretty atrocious  goods like a USB power adapter that has the USB shield bonded to the neutral in one orientation, and *hot* in the other (it's not polarized)